# Pulling a substring in Julia

Tags: julia, substring

I’m working with XML embedded in a syslog message.  I used Python to remove the information outside of the `<>`.  Since I’m playing with Julia I’m trying to figure out a way of doing the same thing.  I’ve read about findfirst, but that doesn’t resolve the issue.  This is sample data.

```
Datetime host other stuff <xml data and more data>stuff at the end
```

What I want is just the data between `<>`.  In Python I use

```
print(line[line.find(“<“):line.find(“>”)])
```

Is there anything similar in Julia?

TIA
Joe

Comment: The question is a little ambiguous. The Python code, as written returns the empty string if `>` occurs before `<` which is probably not what you want. You presumably want paired `<` and `>`, in which case there's also a question of whether you want to look for the first `>` after an opening `<` or the last `>`, or even more subtle, match up corresponding pairs of `<` and `>`. The regex approach is much more flexible: you can use `<.?*>` for first `>` or `<.*>` for last. If you want paired, you need something more powerful than a regex though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively you can use regular a expression:

```
julia> str = "Datetime host other stuff <xml data and more data>stuff at the end"
"Datetime host other stuff <xml data and more data>stuff at the end"

julia> rx = r"<(.*?)>"
r"<(.*?)>"

julia> match(rx, str)[1]
"xml data and more data"
```

If you wanted to use the approach that Oscar proposes then the correct syntax would be:

```
julia> chop(str[findfirst('<',str):findfirst('>',str)], head=1, tail=1)
"xml data and more data"
```

Finally note that in Python your code does not give you what you want as it produces:

```
>>> line = "Datetime host other stuff <xml data and more data>stuff at the end"
>>> print(line[line.find("<"):line.find(">")])
<xml data and more data
```

and as you can see `<` character is not stripped from the string as you wanted.

Comment: The change Stefan made makes the regexp lazy. The difference will be noticeable if you have multiple `>` characters in the string.

Answer (score 3):

Since it is log processing perhaps the performance is somewhat important.
In that case use `SubString{String}` (which does not make memory copying).
Moreover you probably want to use `findlast` when searching for `'>'`.

```
SubString(line, findfirst('<', line), findlast('>',line))
```

This is non-copying and returns a `SubString{String}` object.

Comment: As a side note `match` returns a `SubString`. Also speaking about speed - I think it is worth to note looking for `'<'` is faster than looking for `"<"`.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the docs for [findfirst](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/#Base.findfirst-Tuple%7BAbstractString,%20AbstractString%7D), it will give you the correct usage. In this case, what you want is `println(line[findfirst(line, “<“):findfirst(line, “>”)])`